# spring security authenticationManager must be specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
...
}}
```

my spring-security:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            password-parameter="passwordField" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

i'm trying to add my custom filter in spring security, but on startup i get an error that  authenticationManager must be specified. Can someone have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an `@Autowired` to setter of `AuthenticationManager`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
@Override
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add `alias="authenticationManager"` for your Authentication Manager

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```